# Why I can’t see the elements in the webpage?

Tags: html, css

Here a picture of the problem :
[image]

What I have checked : They have a size and a css and I tried to to use firefox 3D to see if there were any element on them.

(To produce the bug, you have to click on the green button)
http://goldiman3.alwaysdata.net/#

Thank you
Goldiman

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: The direct parent element has an opacity set to 0 with this class: `object-non-visible`. Simply remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the parent element has `opacity 0`

Set opacity to 1 on `.object-non-visible` in your css

[image]

(the highlighted one)

Comment: Thank you, I got it now, but why does this work on the main page before clicking on the button?

Comment: because that same element before clicking the button has a `object-visible` class with a value of `opacity: 1 !important`. After clicking on it, that class doesn't exist.

Comment: Because the class object-non-visivble is added to your col-md-8